# Warning: can't find referenced method 'int save(int)' in library class android.graphics.Canvas

Tags: android, proguard

I'm using a no-longer maintained Umano's [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library in one of my applications:

```
dependencies {
    // .. redacted
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
}
```

Everything worked fine till now. Today I've tried to change the `compileSdkVersion` from 27 to 28, and the release build started to fail with a Proguard error (`minifyEnabled` set to **true**):

```
$ ./gradlew clean assembleRelease

> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
ProGuard, version 6.0.3
Reading input...
// many lines with 'Reading program jar...', redacted
Initializing...
Warning: com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout: can't find referenced method 'int save(int)' in library class android.graphics.Canvas
// redacted
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I'm using AGP v3.5.0, with `android.enableR8=false` configuration to favor Proguard over R8.

One of the comments in [this issue](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/921) suggests to ignore the warning using `-dontwarn com.sothree.**`, which indeed causes the build to pass.

Why this warning started to appear in the first place, and are there any possible ramifications for ignoring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze the warning message:

> Warning: com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout: can't find
>   referenced method 'int save(int)' in library class
>   android.graphics.Canvas

Library's `SlidingUpPanelLayout.java` source file indeed [includes](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/45a460435b07e764138a700328836cafc1ed5c42/library/src/main/java/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java#L1189) a `android.graphics.Canvas#save(int)` method invocation:

```java
final int save = canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
```

This method is [deprecated since API 26](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java#401), and was [marked as @removed in API 28](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/pie-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java#409).
The `@removed` annotation (along with `@hide` annotation) is being used by [doclava](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/doclava/+/refs/heads/oreo-release) tool (AOSP tool which generates public framework API stub, a.k.a. `android.jar`) to mark public class methods as hidden.

To summarize: the `android.graphics.Canvas#save(int)` method was removed from the public API, but it is still part of the runtime/framework (see also [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110856542#comment14)). During minification stage Proguard analyzes the bytecode and obviously fails to find the not-anymore-public-api `android.graphics.Canvas#save(int)` method and displays the above warning.
This method is still present in runtime, therefore Proguard warning can be ignored given two caveats:

- Since this method is not part of public API anymore, a particular vendor might alter the framework classes (i.e., by renaming/removing this method) in a way which will cause runtime errors.
- This method might be removed in future AOSP version, and you probably won't notice that till this method will be called on affected device.

The warning ignore rule can be narrowed to:

```
-dontwarn com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
```

In a long run, I'd suggest to consider patching this library by yourself (by changing the functionality to use the parameterless `android.graphics.Canvas#save()` method), or if that's not possible - migrate to another solution.

Comment: Working perfect. Thanks!